# Animation Path Hierarchy problems

Tags: animation

I've recently moved onto the task of animating for a few simple rigid models, and am having a lot of trouble
 with understanding offsets and bone Hierarchy/relations.

I'm trying to make a miniature train with a body following a path, and a set of rotating wheels and cranks that do 
revolutions constantly, while maintaining position and rotation in relation to the parent bone/body.

(This is for the Source Engine, so I'm using **Vertex groups with bone parents**, all part of a **single armature** and a **single object**.)

I can do all of these animations seperately without issue, including the path animation, the cyclic pieces, linear extrapolation for speed etc. and can save and export the "Action" from the path as keyframes, but I cannot get the parenting to work without things having their offsets being misplaced, warping, gradually moving out of position etc.

The way bones and objects move around between Edit, Pose and Object mode is also very confusing, considering some of these problems seem to be offset and origin based, leading to more confusion when trying to reposition them.

I had assumed I would just need to have each animation/action bake ready seperately per bone, then move the child bones (And attached Vertex groups) in relative position to the parent, create the hierarchy then add the Parent path constraint, I must be doing everything wrong as Blender seems to want to
make this very difficult for me.

I have a feeling this is a very basic sort of question, but I cannot find help for this case anywhere, almost all path animation tutorials don't even attempt to explain how hierarchy works when multiple moving/animated parts are set up.

Even a very basic .Blend file a few text pointers would be of great use to me, I should be able to work out everything else myself after seeing even one working example.

- I was considering adding pictures, but I doubt in this case it would be of any use.